# Removing BBCode URL tag from string

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, htmlpurifier

Im trying to make a stable system that will allow users to paste any mixture of BB / Html code into an input and i will sanitize and strip the data AS I WANT.

The content is copied from forums and the issue is that they all seems to use different code. Some display more than one 
 some use a self closing br tag. Others use a [URL =] And other just use [URL]URL[/URL] etc.

So far, I use HTMLpurifier to strip everything except for img tags.

HTMLpurifier doesnt (as far as i can see) remove BBCode. So, given a string like so:

```
[URL=http://awebsite.com]My Link [IMG]imagelink.png[/IMG][/URL]
```

How can i remove the URL tags and just leave the IMG tags.

I want to remove all the URL tag options so the url given and the text as well which may prove difficult.

So far i have got quite far by converting [IMG] tags etc using REGEX which works but i feel there are too many variants to hardcode this.

Any suggestions on a more efficient way / possible way to remove the URL tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you just want to remove tags such as `[URL=http://awebsite.com]` and `[/URL]`, leaving the content inside, the regex is simple:

Search: `\[/?URL[^\]]*\]`

Replace: Empty string

**In JavaScript**

```
replaced = string.replace(/\[\/?URL[^\]]*\]/g, "");
```

**In PHP**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%\[/?URL[^\]]*\]%', '', $str);
```

**Option 2: Also Removing content such as `MyLink`**

Here, we'll replace the content following `[URL...]` that is not another tag.

Search: `\[URL[^\]]*\][^\[\]]*|\[/URL[^\]]*\]`

Replace: Empty string

**JavaScript:**

```
replaced = string.replace(/\[URL[^\]]*\][^\[\]]*|\[\/URL[^\]]*\]/g, "");
```

**PHP:**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%\[URL[^\]]*\][^\[\]]*|\[/URL[^\]]*\]%', '', $str);
```

Comment: amazing! Work perfectly! Didnt think it would be possible but a bit of regex magic and it works. Really need to have a good learn of creating regex. Last question @zx81 is there a way to make the URL part in the regex non case sensitive? sometimes people use lower case url tags. I could use two different preg_replaces, One with lower case and the other upper but that seems silly if theres a way to do it non case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: `Really need to have a good learn of creating regex.` Well if you're starting to study more regex and are interested in collecting cool techniques, maybe you'd like to look at this question about a very common problem, [(matching... except)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/) or save it for later. I had  a lot of fun writing the answer. :)

Comment: Ill take a look! So much in my learning list bookmarks right now :) Have upvoted too!

Comment: Thanks, see you next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to extract only `IMG` tags using regex:

```
$pattern ="#\[IMG\](https?://[-\w\.]+(:\d+)?/[\w/_\.]*(\?\S+?)?)?\[\/IMG\]#";
$str = "[URL=http://awebsite.com]My Link [IMG]http://google.com/imagelink.png[/IMG][/URL]";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [IMG]http://google.com/imagelink.png[/IMG]
    [1] => http://google.com/imagelink.png
)
```